# No ARIMA, No GARCH, which model?

Tags: self-study, arima, model, garch

I am trying to fit a model for a data set.
The acf and pacf, after differentiating the data are: 
[image]

The acf shows that the returns appeared to be random. According to them seems like the ARIMA model is not a good fit for the data.
I square the observations and run a new acf plot on this new data set of squared returns, waiting to find a GARCH pattern, but again the  acf appeared to be random:
[image]

Which model do you think it would be convenient to use to fit the data?

DATA

```
10346 13698 13894 19854 28066 26620 27066 16658  9221 13578 11483 10390 11126 13487 
15851 16116 24102 30892 25081 14067 10433 15591  8639 10345 10639 15796 14507 21289 
25444 26149 23612 19671 12447 13535 10667 11255  8442 11546 15958 21058 28088 23827 
30707 19653 12791 13463 11465 12326 12277 12769 18341 19140 24590 28277 22694 15489 
11070 11002 11579  9834  9364 15128 15147 18499 25134 32116 24475 21952 10272 15404 
13079 10633 10761 13714 16073 23335 29822 26800 31489 19780 12238 15318  9646 11786 
10906 13056 17599 22524 25057 28809 27880 19912 12319 18240 11934 10290 11304 16092 
15911 24671 31081 27716 25388 22665 10603 14409 10736  9651 12533 17546 16863 23598 
25867 31774 24216 20448 12548 15129 11687 11581
```

Answer (score 2):

Transformations like drugs can be bad for you. The only time an ARCH/GARCH is needed is if the error variance changes stochastically over time. Here is a useful model[image] with actual fit and forecast[image] . The forecasts are here [image] . A plot of the residuals suggests randomness [image] which is confirmed by the acf of the residuals [image] . All models are wrong but this one seems useful. The combination of ARIMA structure and 5 seasonal dummies renders the error process to be white noise thus effectively decomposing the observation set to signal and noise.

The reason your software failed to identify the appropriate model was that it'S model identification approach is limited. Simple solutions can often work for simple problems. When data is not simple ( as in nearly always ! ) you may need more sophisticated model identification procedures. The ACF/PACF of the original series is of little value when there are deterministic components such as seasonal dummies/level shifts/pulses/local time trends in the data.

Comment: For the record, the following statement is incorrect: *The only time an ARCH/GARCH is needed is if the error variance changes stochastically over time.* ARCH/GARCH models imply deterministic conditional variance and that is one major way in how they differ from stochastic volatility (SV) models. To see this, take a look at the ARCH/GARCH equation for the conditional variance: it does not have an error term at the end. The current period's conditional variance is completely determined by past shocks/innovations in ARCH models and also by past conditional variances in GARCH models.